# Can't import from views.py django

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my views.py file.

```
def home(request):
    fromDate = request.GET.get('fromDate', 'This is a default value')
    toDate = request.GET.get('toDate', 'This is a default value')
```

I want to import fromDate and toDate from views.py to another file I created (countries.py), but every time I try to use

```
from . import views
```

I get the error.

```
partially initialized module 'website.views' has no attribute 'toDate' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Even using

```
from website import views # gives the same error
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you cannot directly import variables to another file. You can import function/Class

Comment: @HemalPatel You can import variables into a module. But that have to be global variables in the other module, and the one attempted to be imported here is local to the function.

Comment: @Fakhr Ali share the directory structure as well

Comment: 'website.views' has no attribute 'toDate' as per this line in error  toDate is local to view function home and thats the case django is complaining about.

Comment: `from . import views` should not give you this error, which makes your example and error unreproducible. But overall, you shouldn't attempt to import variables local to a function. You need to rethink your code layout and may need to restructure things.

Comment: @9769953 True!!

Comment: Adding to @9769953 don't try to use global variables for this as you seem to be getting this data from a request. Requests should be stateless and any data needed should be stored somewhere and retrieved by the server on the next request.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm trying to get the values from two date inputs from html. What should I do to get these values, if what I'm doing is not the correct way. Also don't understand what you mean by "data needs to be stored somewhere and retrieved".

Comment: @9769953 I tried using global variables before but I would get the same error. Could you give an example.

Comment: Not really, because generic examples for such imports are strewn across the internet (both good and bad examples, likely). And in your specific case, it is much more likely that you need to rethink your app structure, so that the whole import problem goes away. But that requires much more time, and probably amounts to tutoring, which is not the same as providing a direct solution. A site like [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be of help with that, but a review of the full app code could be a bit much.

Comment: You can pass the data as arguments to the function that needs to use it by calling the function from the view after you receive the data.

If you need to use it later, consider saving it in the database.

Comment: @FakhrAli global variables don't really scale well with web applications, consider the following you store some data for a particular user as a global variable, the next request is by another user but it accesses this data! There are multiple other issues with using global variables. In general you should _store_ the data somewhere, be it the database, the user session, the users cookies, etc. in the next request you can retrieve this data. These terms should be enough for you to research.

Answer (score 0):

Move the 2 variable into a global scope, and not under a fucntion.

```
fromDate = request.GET.get('fromDate', 'This is a default value')
toDate = request.GET.get('toDate', 'This is a default value')
def home(request):
    ...
```

Then import to another file like:

```
from .view import fromDate, toDate
```

ps.

by convention python does not use cammelCase, you
should rename to from_date, to_date